# Thinking about integrals in a different way

Tags: calculus, integration

There's one odd way to think about integration when it comes to interpreting it as a sum. suppose for a second that $x$ is in meters, you could think of distance as an infinite number $n$ of "points" in space, $n→∞$, then in this case $f(x)Δx$ would mean that you now have $nf(x)$.

Now, as usual, you think of $Δx$ as vanishing to $0$, and then think of $f(x)dx[meters]$ as just, nearly, one point times $f(x)$, and so summing all these would get you the sum of all $f(x)$s, in meters that is, so if the integral equals $5.36$, you consider it as the number of points in $5.36$ meters, which is infinite of course, but it's a way of "summing" infinity.

If you think of it this way, it kind of also seems intuitive that the average of $f(x)$ is $$\int_a^b\frac{1}{b-a}f(x)dx~,$$ you're diving by the "number of points" in $b−a$ meters, which corresponds to the number of $f(x)$s. Again, infinite of course, but we're just manipulating infinities using names.

How bizarre is this, and what remarks could you make for such a way of thinking about integrals? Where can this pose problems?

Comment: You words: "summing all these would get you the sum of all f(x)s,...", The area is not the sum of all the f(x)s. An approximate area may be so if you divide it to rectangles where one side is of length 1 and the other side is of length f(x). Also, in this case the distance between the points a,b divided by length 1 is finite.

Comment: if you continued what's after that and connected it to what's before, you'd see the point.